# Thymeleaf, get current date and subtract x amount of days

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to implement an if statement on my Thymeleaf template that will change the colour of a value based on the current time (minus a specific amount of days).

Now from my understanding there are three ways to declare a date in Thymeleaf:

```
//For the new LocalDateTime, LocalDate classes
#temporals.createNow() 

//For an instance of java.util.Date
#dates.createNow()

//For an instance of java.util.Calendars
#calendars.createNow()
```

Now my model uses instances of java.util.LocalDate so I tried tackling the problems in two different ways (unsuccessfully).

The first thing that come into my mind was to implement the following:

```
td th:if="${user.expiry_date.isBefore(#temporals.createNow().minus(7, ChronoUnit.DAYS))}"
                th:text="${#dates.format(user.expiry_date, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}"style="color: red"/>
```

But I get the following SpelEvaluationException:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'DAYS' cannot be found on null
```

The other approach would be to subtract the date on the server and pass the value through a variable:

```
//method in the @Controller class
    model.addAttribute("userList", organisationService.getAllOrganisations());
        **model.addAttribute("localDateNow", LocalDate.now().minusDays(7));**
```

But even then, accessing another variable inside the same spel expression seems impossible, or at least all my attempts failed:

```
    <td th:if="${user.expiry_date.isBefore(localDateNow)}"
        th:text="${#dates.format(user.expiry_date, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}"style="color: orange"/>
```

and:

```
    <td th:if="${user.expiry_date.isBefore(${localDateNow})}"
        th:text="${#dates.format(user.expiry_date, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}"style="color: orange"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first case, you can't directly call classes by name I believe. you'd have to do `"${user.expiry_date.isBefore(#temporals.createNow().minus(7, T(java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit).DAYS))}"`

And for the second I think you should be using `${#temporals.format()}` as you'r using LocalDateTime not the clasic Date object but as theres no stacktrace given this is just a guess

Comment: Unfortunately getting a "Instantiation of new objects and access to static classes or parameters is forbidden in this context" from the minus method...